# how do I merge arrays in php even if one of those arrays is null?

Tags: php, array-merge

Riht now I use `array_merge_recursive` but if one of my 3 arrays is null I get for `echo json_encode($array4);`

```
null
```

I have 3 `arrays` in my `php` file:

```
$array1 = json_decode($array1, TRUE);
$array2 = json_decode($array2, TRUE);
$array3 = json_decode($array3, TRUE);
```

If I `echo` each of the arrays:

`echo json_encode($array1);` =  `{"results":[{"cat_id":2,"cat_name":"bicycle repairs"}]}`

`echo json_encode($array2);` = `{"results":[{"cat_id":"4","cat_name":"plumber"},{"cat_id":"5","cat_name":"Electrician"},{"cat_id":"6","cat_name":"vet"}]}`

`echo json_encode($array3);`= `{"results":[{"cat_id":3,"cat_name":"Doctor"}]}`

And then I merge these arrays together like this:

```
$array4 = array_merge_recursive($array1['results'], $array2['results'], $array3['results']);
```

Which would give me:

```
[{"cat_id":2,"cat_name":"bicycle repairs"},{"cat_id":"4","cat_name":"plumber"},{"cat_id":"5","cat_name":"Electrician"},{"cat_id":"6","cat_name":"vet"},{"cat_id":3,"cat_name":"Doctor"}]
```

But if any of `$array1`, `$array2` or `$array3` is null then `$array4` doesn't work. How can I overcome this?

Comment: `!is_null($array2['results']) ? $array2['results'] : []`

Comment: @swonder that will generate a warning/notice when there is no key called `results` in `null`.

Comment: Add isset() on the start, then check if it’s null.

Comment: @CHarris here is another technique for you to review: https://3v4l.org/BVFCa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the library only admits arrays as arguments (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php).

So if you want merge all elements I advise you that use ?? (Null Coalescing operator) that return the first params if isset and is not null, you can do something like this:

```
array_merge_recursive($array1['results']??[], $array2['results']??[], $array3['results']??[])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a helper function to check if you variable is an Array. If not just make it an empty one

```
function MakeArray($arr){
    if (!is_array($arr)) return [];
    return $arr;
}
$arr1 = MakeArray([1,2,4]);
$arr2 = MakeArray([5,6]);
$arr3 = MakeArray(NULL);
```

This way you can guarantee that it will work even if you pass, for example, a string